# Modular C# Error

Tags: c#, methods, module

In class we are learning how to develop modular programs in C#. We have to execute the following:

> //public static int promptForInput(string prompt). Prompts for user input, displaying "prompt". User response will be passed back to calling program.

I have the following code:

```
using System;
class RockPaperScissors
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {

    }
    //public static int promptForInput(string prompt)
    //Prompts for user input, displaying "<prompt>". User response will be passed back to calling program
    public static int promptForInput(string prompt)
    {

    }
}
```

The issue is, even that is giving me the following error in VS:

> Error 1   'RockPaperScissors.promptForInput(string)': not all code paths
>   return a value    C:\Users\Maria\Documents\C#Files\Mod
>   5\ConsoleApplication4\ConsoleApplication4\Program.cs  10  23  ConsoleApplication4

How can I ask the user to enter a value in my prompt method and have the Main method display that value? Any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: return a value in the `promptForInput` function.

Comment: Read about [Console.ReadLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.console.readline(v=vs.110).aspx) to understand how you can capture user input. Secondly, you should also learn about how to invoke PromptForInput function from within Main. The compiler error is because you've not returned any value from PromptForInput

Comment: Even if I add Console.Read(); to the promptForInput and promptForInput() in the main method, nothing is transferring over. I can get the following to work: 

using System;
class RockPaperScissors
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Method2();
    }
    public static void Method2()
    {
        Console.WriteLine("test");
        Console.Read();
    }  
}

but for some reason the original won't.

Answer (score 0):

This error means exactly what it says - `promptForInput` doesn't return anything. The method signature "promises" the compiler that you'll throw an `int` and you don't.

If you want to return something, you should do something like:

```
 public static int promptForInput(string prompt)
{
    int ret = int.Parse(Console.Read());
    return ret;
}
```

Disclaimer: I'm not sitting in front of an IDE. Also, this'll throw an exception if the user enters something other than a number.

Comment: Awesome thanks for the help. I changed my code to that but it's displaying an error saying "Argument 1: cannot convert from 'int' to 'string'". Again, really new to all of this and my instructor is horrible so just trying to truly understand what is happening without just copying his code down. Is this because it is expecting a "string prompt"? Thanks for the patience.